# WPF: Center the OpenFileDialog in Window and disable resizing and moving

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

In WPF: When I called OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() it displayed on top left corener of the parent window, but I want to display it in center, and I also want to disable resizing and moving of OpenFileDialog.

Answer (score 0):

you can use position to open in center of screen , below is the link may help -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formstartposition.aspx

also

[WPF : How to set a Dialog position to show at the center of the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306593/wpf-how-to-set-a-dialog-position-to-show-at-the-center-of-the-application)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Here whatever you suggested it is for System.Windows.Form not for OpenFileDialog, as OpenFileDialog has not Owner property.