# WPF Office Add-In: How to set a Dialog position to show at the center of the parent window

Tags: c#, wpf, office-addins

This is an extension of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306593/wpf-how-to-set-a-dialog-position-to-show-at-the-center-of-the-application).

I have made the below minor adjustments for the code to work in case of an Office Add-In.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
if (app.ActiveWindow() != null)
{
   this.Left = app.ActiveWindow().Left + (app.ActiveWindow().Width - this.Width) / 2;
   this.Top = app.ActiveWindow().Top + (app.ActiveWindow().Height - this.Height) / 2;
}
```

This works fine under normal condition but not under HiDPI conditions (e.g. on a Mac with high resolution). The popup windows displayed off the screen in the bottom right corner. Looking at the number the app.ActiveWindow().Width seems huge compare to the other values.

I did not manage to get the good [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6530775/2800651) from @chessweb to work as the calling windows is a button from the ribbon.

Any idea?

Comment: did you try WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" ?

Comment: Hi @AntoineV. Yes but it des not work as Owner and OwnedWindows are null. I open the Windows from the ribbon of the office application. I am not sure if I have a way to set the owner manually under this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well with a bit of testing, I end up with the below solution which works well.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
if (app.ActiveWindow() != null) {
  double WidthRatio = (1 / SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth) * 
  System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromHandle(new 
  WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle).Bounds.Width;
  double HeightRatio = (1 / SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight) * 
  System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromHandle(new 
  WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle).Bounds.Height;
  this.Left = (app.ActiveWindow().Left + (app.ActiveWindow().Width - this.Width * WidthRatio) / 2) / WidthRatio;
  this.Top = (app.ActiveWindow().Top + (app.ActiveWindow().Height - this.Height * HeightRatio) / 2) / HeightRatio;
}
```

Note that:

- For a reason that I can't explain the height ratio is not perfect (
  1.12 instead of 1 when no scaling / 2.12 when working with a scaling factor of 2)
- Under the assumption that height and width scaling factors are equal,
  only one can be used and thus address the first point

Any comment/feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few ways, but this is how I would likely approach it:

1. Get handle from active Outlook Window.
2. Set parent on your Window.

To get the handle, use this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

  //use pInvoke to find the window
  [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

  //now use it
  public static void Test(long handle)
  {
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
      IntPtr hWnd = (IntPtr)FindWindow("rctrl_renwnd32\0", app.ActiveWindow().Caption);

      TestingWindowView win = new TestingWindowView(hWnd);
      win.ShowDialog();
  }
```

Then, in the constructor of your window, you can use `WindowInteropHelper` to assign the owner:

```
using System.Windows.Interop;

    public TestingWindowView(IntPtr handle)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        new WindowInteropHelper(this).Owner = handle;
    }
```

and in xaml, you can now do this:

```
WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
```

I am sure there are other ways to get a handle for Outlook, but this one is tried tested and true.

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi @Nik, thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I have multiple popup windows and therefore the proposal is not ideal. I must say that I also did not get it to work for some reasons. The handle is correctly initialised and set but the windows is still not centered (top left corner now).