# WPF Popup in the middle of another window

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I have a popup window (PopupWindow1) that I have opened on button click like this:

```
PopupWindow1 ad = new PopupWindow1();
ad.ShowDialog();
```

I want to be able to open the popup window in the middle of the window I opened it from. How would I be able to do this? I have tried doing something like this:

```
WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
```

But I have received no luck. Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you share the minimal reproducible sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6530775/11132882
The missing part you need may be `ad.Owner = this;`