# XAML enable/disable view from another view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm a beginner and having some dicciculties with XAML.
I have a main view A, which has a button to open a pop-up-window B. When this happens, Window A should still be visible and openened, but disabled. I've done this in code behind (maybe not the cleanest way, but the only way I know how). The code i used for this is the following:

```
//Code behind from view A
        private void X-Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var BWindow = new BView();
            BWindow.Show();
            this.IsEnabled = false;
        }
```

I would like to get window A enabled again once i close window B, but i can t seem to get this work. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You are right. This is not the clean way. Anyway, you can pass the `AView` as argument to `BView` and enable it on `BView` close.

Comment: What is the code for closing window B?

Comment: The behavior that you describe remind me a Child window. I recomend you take a look to the Extended WPF Toolkit library. There you can find a ChildWindow implementation:http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ChildWindow&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in the following way.

You register yourself on the Closed event of the window, and when it gets closed, you unregister the event, and re-enable the this form.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window BWindow = new BWindow();
    BWindow.Show();
    BWindow.Closed += BWindow_Closed;
    this.IsEnabled = false;
}

void BWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Window win = sender as Window;
    if (win != null)
    {
        win.Closed -= BWindow_Closed;
    }
    this.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for modal window. See similar question asked here: [How do make modal dialog in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499294/how-do-make-modal-dialog-in-wpf)

The solution is in using `ShowDialog` method from `Window` class. See here for reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx

Modal window is the concept when you open new window B from the existing window A. While the B is open, the A is disabled and cannot be used. Window A become active only when the B is closed.