# Displaying modal window from WPF Browser Application, e.g. MessageBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

The native WPF MessageBox calls UnsafeNativeMethods.GetActiveWindow(), this appears to locate Internet Explorer and set IE as the owner of the dialog. Evk provided instructions for accessing this method, but the window is still not modal. There is more going on that I don't understand, I would like to lock out IE until a user returns from my own custom dialog.

```
public DialogResult ShowInput<T>(string messageText, string caption, out T input)
{
    var window = new InputDialog<T>(messageText, caption);

    var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
    helper.Owner = NativeMethods.GetActiveWindow();

    if (window.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        input = window.Input;
        return DialogResult.OK;
    }
    else
    {
        input = default(T);
        return DialogResult.Cancel;
    }
}

public static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();
}
```

Comment: What has a WPF messagebox to do with IE? If you want to show a modal dialog, [just use what WPF offers you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499294/how-do-make-modal-dialog-in-wpf)... If that is not what you asked for, please be more specific with your question.

Comment: @elgonzo If you create a WPF browser application, and launch it using IE when you call ShowDialog() on a window it doesn't respect IE as a parent, MessageBox.Show does respect IE. I'm wondering how to duplicate this functionality.

Comment: Okay, i have to admit i never did WPF in a browser :(  So you want to block the complete IE, not just the page of your application... hmm...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to do the same as UnsafeNativeMethods.GetActiveWindow does. Then you can just use:

```
public static class NativeMethods {
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();
}
```

Which calls native GetActiveWindow windows api from user32.dll (and this is exactly what UnsafeNativeMethods.GetActiveWindow does).

Comment: Thank you, I was able to use this to set the owner. Unfortunately setting the owner doesn't appear to be the entire solution. The window is now topmost, but modeless. I can interact with my page and IE.