# Prevent Custom Message Dialog ( a modal dialog) focus loss in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing an application and for the custom purposes of the app, I need a custom `MessageBox`.

I've created a new WPF `Window` and I'd like to force the user to interact with the custom message box before returning to the application, thus preventing them from using the application until a button inside the custom message box is pressed.

I've tried using `.Focus()` but it didn't work at all.

To give a perfect example of exactly what I want:

Try to press "Save As" in Outlook and then click on the "Mail" window again.
You instantly get "redirected" to the "Save As" Dialog and can't do anything on the main window until the dialog is closed.

Any ideas how to make this possible?

Comment: Do you show your custom messagebox via ShowDialog call? If not - use it instead of just Show.

Comment: Of course, if I understand the question, you want to make it the custom `MessageBox` a modal dialog, right? You could rephrase the question as how to create a modal window

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499294/how-do-make-modal-dialog-in-wpf)

Comment: @afaolek to be honest, phrase "modal dialog/window" is a phrase I've never heard before. I've got quite a bit of programming experience, but terms and theory side I'm in the gutter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you want your new `Window` to be modal. The way to do it in WPF is to call the `ShowDialog` method rather than just `Show`

Comment: Just like that, huh? This was way more easier that I have expected it to be. This works fine and it solved the issue, thank you! :)

Comment: @DethoRhyne you're welcome, it's easier when you know what to look for ! Do no forget to mark your question as resolved

Comment: Very true indeed. And of course, I couldn't at the time due to time limit but I did now!