# Button clicked once

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I have a problem with the option to select the button once when it is open, what am I doing wrong?

```
private Boolean buttonWasClicked = false;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        buttonWasClicked = true;



        if ( buttonWasClicked == true)
        {
         new SettingsWindow().Show();
        var test = new SettingsWindow();
        test.Owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;
        test.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
        test.Top = this.Top + 20;

        }
        else {

            buttonWasClicked = false;
        }


   }`
```

Comment: Winform or ASP.NET? What you are trying to do BTW?

Comment: using WPF in visual studio C#

Comment: You are creating two copies of `SettingsWindow`, you likely don't want that

Comment: the problem is that i want not open another window when it is already open

Comment: If you want to open it as a dialog, you could use `OpenDialog`: [How do make modal dialog in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/499304/1115360)

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid to keep your own flag variable and manage its setting by hand. For example, if the user closes the window how do you change back the variable to allow again opening a SettingsWindow?. There is a more robust system based approach at this problem. Looking at system provided informations will help you  to avoid opening a second time the settings window until there is already one instance opened.

To check if there is already an instance of a SettingsWindow open you could use informations provided by the system with code like this

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if, in the Application.Current.Windows collection 
    // there is at least one window of type SettingsWindow
    SettingsWindow w = Application.Current.Windows
                                  .OfType<SettingsWindow>()
                                  .FirstOrDefault();

    if(w == null)
    {
        // No window of the type required, open a new one....
        w = new SettingsWindow();
        w.Owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;
        w.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
        w.Top = this.Top + 20;
    }

    // Show it NON MODALLY....
    w.Show();
}
```

The call to `Show` returns immediately (Non modally) and thus your program continue as usual with the MainWindow still active.
Instead, if you want to use a modal approach, (meaning that until the `SettingsWindow` is open nothing in your MainWindow is active) you could simply create the SettingsWindow, set its Owner and eventually its Position and finally call `ShowDialog` (Do not forget to set the Owner property). In this way your code is blocked in the ShowDialog and doesn't return until the user closes the SettingsWindow instance just opened. (And you could remove all the checking above)

Comment: Thank you ! It's also what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this will always be true 
Go with the excellent answer from Steve

```
buttonWasClicked = true;
if (buttonWasClicked == true)
{
   // this will execute every time
}
else 
{
   // this will never execute
}
```