# WPF - Limiting user interaction to topmost window similarly to a MessageBox

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

I am creating a WPF application and have a exit button which allows the user to exit the application. To exit the application I decided to design a new window which ask the user if they want to exit the application with two buttons simiarl to the `MessageBox` window. I chose to do this over a `MessageBox` so I could style the elements in the window.

However an important feature about `MessaegBox` is that it prevents the user from interacting with the window behind the `MessageBox`. For example when I used `MessageBox` it became the topmost window and I could only interact with this window, but in my custom window I do not have this functionality.

Can I implement this so that in my custom window a user can only interact with the topmost window rather either the top (custom exit window) or window behind (`MainWindow`)?

Comment: `CustomeWindow.ShowDialog();` instead of just `Show();`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499294/how-to-make-modal-dialog-in-wpf

Comment: @Rao Hammas Hussain. Thanks for the comment, just tried this and its working as desired. Thanks again!

Comment: Also you can set `CustomeWindow.Owner = this`; before `CustomeWindow.ShowDialog();`

Comment: @Anonymous great :)